# How to filter a list of tuples based on matching one item of the tuple to another list through lambda expression in C#?

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a list of tuples:

`List<Tuple<string, string>> keys = { ("AB","12"), ("BC","23"), ("XY","00")}`

I have another enumerable collection of strings:

`IEnumerable<string> results = {"ABC", "BCD", "ZZXY"}`

I am trying to write a lambda expression that would give me the list of all the keys such that there is a corresponding result (in the `results` list) that starts with `keys.item1`.

So finally, I want the following:

`List<Tuple<string, string>> finalKeys = { ("AB","12"), ("BC","23") }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `Where` statement with a corresponding `Any` call:

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> finalKeys = keys
    .Where(key => results.Any(result => result.StartsWith(key.Item1)))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
         List<Tuple<string, string>> keys = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
         {
            new Tuple<string, string>("AB", "12"),
            new Tuple<string, string>("BC", "23"),
            new Tuple<string, string>("XY", "00")
         };

         IEnumerable<string> results = new List<string> {"ABC", "BCD", "ZZXY"};

         var finalKeys = keys.Where(f => results.Any(m => m.StartsWith(f.Item1))).ToList();
```